# Mapping caps-lock to escape in VS2013 with Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey, visual-studio-2013

I am attempting to create a conditional mapping for VS2013 with autohotkey to map caps-lock to escape in the editor.

However it is not working and I think it may be because I can't get the correct window title to put in the script. Auto hotkey Window Spy just shows:

```
>>>>>>>>>>( Window Title & Class )<<<<<<<<<<<
branch • Solutiuon Name (Debug|Mixed Platforms) - Microsoft Visual Studio
ahk_class HwndWrapper[DefaultDomain;;8c1259b3-5bbb-4676-945d-a1a521bb7f16]
```

or is there something else wrong with the script?

```
#SingleInstance

SetTitleMatchMode,2
#IfWinActive,wndclass_desked_gsk
   CAPSLOCK::ESC
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are missing just one thing, the `ahk_class` in your `#IfWinActive` statement.

This command assumes that without declaring it as a class, you are using the Window Title (which is not what you are trying to do).

Try the following for that line:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class wndclass_desked_gsk
```

If that doesn't work, it is an issue with your window class.  You could always do the window title instead:

```
#IfWinActive, Microsoft Visual Studio
```

Comment: Thanks - The title detection version worked great. I think the wndclass one was problematic is it was that wrapper type with a guid in it etc.